# CoordinatorLayout class not found

Tags: android

I am currently using a CoordinatorLayout in one of my xml files. It is my first time using it actually. There were no errors prior to the coding itself but when I try to see the design of the xml it always says CoordinatorLayout class not found.  The same goes for my TextInputLayout.

Here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.exceptions.chatt.LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

And here is my build gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
          compileSdkVersion 25
          buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
          defaultConfig {
                 applicationId "com.exceptions.chatt"
                 minSdkVersion 19
                 targetSdkVersion 25
                 versionCode 1
                 versionName "1.0"
                 testInstrumentationRunner                                              
                "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
          release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                  }
     }
   }

   dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
         compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"
         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
         testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The API level in which I was trying to see the design was 25. I have also updated my Android Studio recently. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add this to your dependancy:

```
dependancy{
....
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
}
```

Sync and run. Hope this fixes the issue

Comment: It worked! I thought adding the latest support version would fix it. Turns out I need to add design itself. Thank you so much!